# How to implement Elasticsearch advanced search with DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to implement a search in Elastic Search with Django Rest Framework. I have a form for searching as follows.
[image]

I used a serializer to implement this form.

search.py:

```
class AdvancedSearch(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
serializer_class = AdvancedSearchSerializer

def query_builder(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ## building related query
    return query

@get_db()
def get_queryset(self, db=None, *args, **kwargs):

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    query = self.query_builder(search_input=serializer.validated_data)
    response = db.search(query) # query the elastic with elasticsearch-dsl and return the results

    if not response:
        raise NoteFound()
    return response

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    self.serializer_class = AdvancedSearchSerializer
    return super(AdvancedSearch, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

serializer.py:

```
class AdvancedSearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

metadata_choices = [('', ''), ...]
name = serializers.CharField(required=False, label='Name')
type = serializers.CharField(required=False, label='Type')
metadata = serializers.CharField(required=False, label='Metadata')
metadata_fields = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(allow_blank=True, choices=metadata_choices)
submit_date = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

def to_representation(self, instance):
    output = {}
    output['es_id'] = instance.meta.id
    for attribute_name in instance:
        attribute = getattr(instance, attribute_name)

        if isinstance(attribute, (str, int, bool, float, type(None))):
            # Primitive types can be passed through unmodified.
            output[attribute_name] = attribute

        elif isinstance(attribute, list):
            # Recursively deal with items in lists.
            output[attribute_name] = [
                self.to_representation(item) for item in attribute
            ]

        elif isinstance(attribute, (dict, AttrDict)):
            temp = attribute.to_dict()
            for key, value in temp.items():
                print(key,value)
            # Recursively deal with items in dictionaries.
            output[attribute_name] = {
                str(key): value
                for key, value in temp.items()
            }
        else:
            # Force anything else to its string representation.
            output[attribute_name] = attribute
  
    output['highlight'] = instance.meta.highlight.to_dict()
    return [output]
```

With this code, I get the expected result, but I was wondering if this is a right approach.
And also in to_representation I have access to each result, but how can I add a total value like the number of results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution for this